# How to navigate command options in powershell

Tags: powershell

I found an example where someone switching between command options somehow: https://chocolatey.org/docs/commandslist
[image: command options navigations]

It looks like he uses some hotkey for navigation between command options --pre, --exact, etc. 
What is this hotkey?

Comment: probably tab I suspect, can you check this?  Tab will auto complete the parameters to a PS script for example.

Comment: Tab navigates through files and folder in the current folder.

Comment: on my win7ps5.1 setup, the standard intellisense lets me tab-complete & then work thru all the parameters that fit what i typed before i hit the tab key. this works in the ISE and the console.

Comment: As for this... (Tab navigates through files and folder in the current folder.), intelligence allows both depending on what you type previously, as well as all switches, parameters, etc., whether it's the consolehost, ISE, VSCode. Each has it's own quirks. The author of that post, may have also tweaked their profile, and or PSReadline to meet their needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below to enable tab completion for chocolatey:

```
Import-Module “$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1” -Force
```

This was obtained from this source:

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/763